# different versions of ignored files in different branches

Tags: git

we want to merge our projects from subversion to git, but there is still one problem we need to solve :)

Our situation:
We store our configuration data in one config file. This file needs to bee different in for each branch and each environment. So this file is ignored in subversion.
When we checkout a branch, we copy a sample file and change some values in the file. So everything works fine :)

But how can we handle this in git?
So, when I switch from one branch to another branch on my development box I need a different config file. But the ignored files i my local git repository are all the same for each branch :(

Can anybody give me a hint on this?

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I had this same issue and actually made the config files shared across branches dynamic so they actually picked up what stage they were in and used the appropriate settings. This was for web though, so it may not be applicable for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same [.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file in each branch with its contents being the path to the ignored file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the branch(es) where you want the ignored files to be different, edit /add the `.gitignore` file with appropriate paths / filenames and commit.

For example, in branch1's .gitignore, have:

```
branch1.config
```

For example, in branch2's .gitignore, have:

```
branch2.config
```

Or if the names are similar enough and won't interfere with other files, use wildcards and ignore them, something like:

```
branch*.config
```